How to Query Entries with Specific Decision IDs in MS Access
I have a table named MyTable linked from an external MS Access database (C:\Data\LinkedDatabases\ExternalData.mdb). The table structure includes GroupId, RuleId, and DecisionCode.
I need to create a query that lists all entries from this table where the values 10 and 42 both exist in the DecisionCode field under the same GroupId and RuleId. However, it should only return these entries if both DecisionCode values 10 and 42 exist for the same GroupId and RuleId.
Here is the query I initially wrote, which results in a syntax error:
SELECT A.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM MyTable IN 'C:\Data\LinkedDatabases\ExternalData.mdb') AS A
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM (
    SELECT GroupId, RuleId
    FROM MyTable IN 'C:\Data\LinkedDatabases\ExternalData.mdb'
    WHERE DecisionCode IN (10, 42)
    GROUP BY GroupId, RuleId
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DecisionCode) = 2
) AS B
WHERE A.GroupId = B.GroupId
AND A.RuleId = B.RuleId
)
AND A.DecisionCode IN (10, 42);

I encountered a syntax error: "missing operator in query expression 'COUNT(DISTINCT DecisionCode) = 2'".
I understand that DISTINCT is not supported in the COUNT function in MS Access. How can I rewrite this query to achieve the desired result?
Here’s the revised attempt, which still doesn’t return the correct results:
SELECT A.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM MyTable IN 'C:\Data\LinkedDatabases\ExternalData.mdb') AS A
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM (
        SELECT GroupId, RuleId
        FROM MyTable IN 'C:\Data\LinkedDatabases\ExternalData.mdb'
        WHERE DecisionCode IN (10, 42)
        GROUP BY GroupId, RuleId
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
    ) AS B
    WHERE A.GroupId = B.GroupId
    AND A.RuleId = B.RuleId
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM MyTable AS C
        WHERE C.GroupId = A.GroupId
        AND C.RuleId = A.RuleId
        AND C.DecisionCode = 10
    )
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM MyTable AS D
        WHERE D.GroupId = A.GroupId
        AND D.RuleId = A.RuleId
        AND D.DecisionCode = 42
    )
)
AND A.DecisionCode IN (10, 42);

This query includes nested subqueries to ensure that both DecisionCode 10 and 42 exist for the same GroupId and RuleId. However, it still returns entries that only contain DecisionCode 10.
Any advice on how to correctly structure this query in MS Access?
Example Data:



GroupId
RuleId
DecisionCode




1
15
10


1
15
42


1
16
10


1
17
10


2
15
10


2
16
10


2
16
42


2
17
42


3
15
10


3
16
10


3
17
10



Desired outcome:



GroupId
RuleId
DecisionCode




1
15
10


1
15
42


2
16
10


2
16
42




select * from data as d where exists  (select 1 from data as d2 where d2.groupid=d.groupid and d2.ruleid=d.ruleid       and d2.decisioncode=10) and exists  (select 1 from data as d2 where d2.groupid=d.groupid and d2.ruleid=d.ruleid  and d2.decisioncod=42)          Ive not tested this.

@Nathan_Sav, your proposed solution also yields DecisionCodes (10 or 42) while its counterpart (10 or 42) does not exist under the same GroupId and RuleId.

You tagged this question for mysql, but the question appears to be about Microsoft Access only. Can you clarify if you are really using MySQL, and if not, please do not use irrelevant tags.

Make sure GroupID and RuleID pair is IN set filtered for 42 AND set filtered for 10:
SELECT MyTable.*
FROM MyTable
WHERE GroupID & ":" & RuleID IN 
    (SELECT GroupID & ":" & RuleID FROM MyTable WHERE DecisionCode = 42) 
AND GroupID & ":" & RuleID IN 
    (SELECT GroupID & ":" & RuleID FROM MyTable WHERE DecisionCode =10);


it is running for 5 minutes now and only passed 5% on the status bar. I'll share the outcome once finished.

How many records are in table?

279.638 records

Maybe it would be faster if table has a compound index for these two fields.

1 and 11 will equate to 11 and 1 for example, maybe use as separator between or even join on the 2 fields rather than concatenate.

It has been running for almost 20 minutes now and completed only 10%. Unfortunately, I am not able to create a compound index for these fields. Might there be an alternative approach

I tested mine and @Nathan_Sav versions with 286,011 records. Datasheet opens in a few seconds but moving to last record takes forever for both. Had to use TaskManager to kill process. Only alternative I can see would involve VBA and possibly temp table. I tried a JOIN approach and couldn't get it. Yes, some separator character would be good idea, space or semicolon (edited answer). However, doesn't change performance.

I made a stab at using VBA and it didn't help. Sorry. Maybe time to move data to SQLServerExpress or MySQL.

the following solved it:
SELECT A.* FROM MyTable AS A INNER JOIN MyTable AS B     ON A.RuleId = B.RuleId     AND A.GroupId = B.GroupId WHERE A.DecisionCode IN (10, 42)   AND B.DecisionCode IN (10, 42)   AND A.DecisionCode <> B.DecisionCode ORDER BY A.RuleId, A.GroupId;

Glad you found solution. I tested with the table I built and never could get it to open. Must be because the dataset is the same 10 records repeated 28600 times.


    select * from data as d 
where exists  
(select 1 from data as d2 where d2.groupid=d.groupid and d2.ruleid=d.ruleid                         and d2.decisioncode=10) 
and exists  (select 1 from data as d2 where d2.groupid=d.groupid and d2.ruleid=d.ruleid  and d2.decisioncode=42)

